# Android - Transforming user coordinate system based on imageview.matrix

Tags: android, matrix

I have a graphing application that has an image displayed on screen.  The image is dependent on internal variables for minimum and maximum X and Y coordinates.

For example the default coordinates may be from (-5,-5) to (+5,+5).  Using these coordinates I draw the contents of the image.  Think of a complex graph/image that can be panned and zoomed.

In Android I use an onTouchListener, postScale, postTranslate and setImageMatrix.  This allows the user to drag and pinch zoom the onscreen image.  This part works as expected.  The user can pinch zoom and the onscreen image is zoomed in and gets blurry.  The problem comes when they release their finger(s) and I need to regenerate the imageview contents.  I need to know how the internal minx, maxx, miny and maxy coordinates changed in relation to the android coordinates.

How can I translate scale my coordinate system by the pan/zoom amounts the user pans and zooms?  I have setup all sorts of bad code to try and push/pull/scale my coordinate system based on the imageview matrix transforms, but nothing works reliably.  Is there a simple set of math formulas to help me do what I want?

I hope this isn't too vague.